# Commutator subgroup having a complement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose we have a finite group $G$ such that $[G,G]$ has a complement in $G$. Then what are some "good" things we can conclude from this situation? I know that "good" is not well-defined, but I am sure there are people on here who would come up with some good facts. Thanks

Comment: well, all nonabelian group of order $pq$ has this property; $|G'|=p$ where $p>q$ and it has a complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another observation, if $H$ is a complement of $G'$, then $H$ is also a complement of each member of the lower central series $\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ for any $i\geq 1$. This can be proved by induction: if $G=HG'$, then it follows that $G'=H'[G',G]$, and this can be substituted in $G=HG'$. In particular, $G$ cannot be nilpotent.

In addition to Mesel's remarks: if $H$ is normal, then $H \subseteq Z(G)$, the center of $G$, since $H \cap G'=1$. In that case, $G=G'Z(G)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice as well.

Answer (score 1):

A few observation;

Let $G=G'H$ where $G'\cap H=1$;

since $G/G'\cong H$ we must have $H$ is a abelian group.

If $H$ is normal in $G$ then $G'$ is a perfect group. (so, $G$ is not solvable)

since  $G= G'\times H\implies G'= G''\times H'$  but since $H$ is abelian $H'=e$
So we have $G'=G''$ so $G'$ is a perfect group.

You can set such group as an example, $G=A_5\times C_2$.

Comment: yes this is a nice observation and i have upvoted the answer, but i will wait and see if i get some other "good" observations before i accept it. Thanks